# Form label/input alignment not as expected in IE7

Tags: forms, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a html5 form which displays as expected in IE8 and above, also in Chrome, Safari, Forefox and Opera. But in IE7 the label alignment is completely different - the labels are displayed above the input fields rather than to the left of them and horizontally aligned which is what I'm after.

I haven't found this question asked on StackOverflow, but did find something very similar looking on CSS tricks. I did have a link here but as a first time poster my question was rejected due to having more than 2 links in it (due to the additional 2 links below showing screenshots of the issue). So I had to remove it... The answer to the post on CSS tricks gives me some areas to look at, but it's not specific - it says "Figured it out on my own. Solution involved a combination of moving the label tags and some IE conditional CSS."

The difference in display of the form is shown in these screenshots:

IE7: http://www.s203574650.websitehome.co.uk/Screenshots/IE7_form.jpg

IE10: http://www.s203574650.websitehome.co.uk/Screenshots/IE10_form.jpg

HTML code:

```
<form id="contact" action="contact_us.php" method="post">
<div>
<label for="fullname">Your Full Name:</label>
<input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="eg. John Smith" required aria-       required="true" >
</div>
<div>
<label for="email">Your Email Address:</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="eg. johnsmith@gmail.com" required aria-    required="true" title="Please enter a valid email address">
</div>
<div>
<label for="phone">Your Phone Number (optional):</label>
<input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="eg. 07000 123456" pattern="([0-9]|( |-)?)    {10,14}" title="Please use only digits, spaces and hyphens.">
</div>
<div>
<label for="experience">Your Badminton Experience:</label>
<select name="experience">
<option value="default">Please Choose</option>
                <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                  <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
                   <option value="Don't know">Don't know</option>
                   </select>                
</div>
 <div>
<label for="club_matches">Have you previously played matches for a club?:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="club_matches" value="Yes">Yes
 <input type="radio" name="club_matches" value="No" checked>No
 </div>
<div>                   
<label for="info">Additional Info / Questions: </label>
<textarea name="info" type="text">
</textarea>
</div>
<div>
<label for="blank"></label>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form" name="sent">
</div>
</form>
```

And the CSS:

```
   /* styles for contact form */
#contact
{
background-color: #DDE2E2;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
border-radius: 10px;
border: solid slategrey 2px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px slategrey;
-o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px slategrey;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px slategrey;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px slategrey;
padding: 3%;
font-family: arial;
color: #0099FF;
font-weight:bold;
align:center;
width: 80%;
margin-left:40px;
}

label
{
width: 40%;
float:left;
text-align:right;
margin-right: 2em;
font-size: 0.8em;
}

label, select, textarea, input
{
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
clear:left;
margin-left: 1em;
}

#submit
{
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: typo: `align:center;` -> `text-align:center;` however, in this case you're probably better off removing this invalid style rather than using `text-align:center`.

Comment: Oops, you're right, have removed that now - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're clearing floats for the select boxes, textareas, and inputs as well as for the labels, when you should only be clearing them for the labels.

```
label, select, textarea, input {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Remove `clear: left;` from the CSS selector for `label, select, textarea, input` and add it to the one for `label`:

```
label {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
label, select, textarea, input {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, and probably related to floats / clears. Looking the same in IE7 now as newer browsers. Thanks!